# validate email with points using regex

Tags: python, regex, email-validation

I want to validate more than 40k emails from a csv file, the problem is that in this file there are some emails with blank spaces or it has only this value `<blank>`. I remove many rows from my dataframe using `df.dropna()`  but yet there are rows with blank spaces. Now I want validate this emails using a regular expression or regex with python and `re` lib.

Here my code:

```
import re

series = pd.Series(['test.123@gmail.com',
                    'two.dots.m12@gmail.com',
                    'test.test2.c@gmail.com.es',
                    'sam_alc12@congreso.gob.pe',
                    'hellowolrd.com',
                    '<blank>'])

regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
for email in series:
   if re.search(regex, email):
      print("{}: Valid Email".format(email))
   else:
      print("{} : Invalid Email".format(email))
```

This was the output:

```
test.123@gmail.com: Valid Email
two.dots.m12@gmail.com : Invalid Email
test.test2.c@gmail.com.es : Invalid Email
sam_alc12@congreso.gob.pe : Invalid Email
hellowolrd.com : Invalid Email
<blank> : Invalid Email
```

However the were 3 incorrect validations with this emails:

```
two.dots.m12@gmail.com
test.test2.c@gmail.com.es
sam_alc12@congreso.gob.pe
```

All them are valid emails.. the current regex can't valida one email with more than 2 dots before of @ and after of @.

I tryed many mods in the current regex but nothing happened.
I also used `email-validator` but it takes a lot of time because is verifying that it is a real email.

Comment: So you just want to check whether the string has some letters/numbers/underscore/dots, followed by an @ sign, followed by more letters/numbers/underscore/dots, yes? You don't need complicated regex for that, just ```"[\w.]+@[\w.]+"``` should work.

Answer (score 0):

For your given examples, the issue is that you are only matching a single time an optional `.` or `_`

Instead, you can optionally repeat matching either one of them to match it multiple times, but not match consecutive `..` or `___`

You don't have to escape the `\.` in the character class, and the `[@]` does not have to be in square brackets.

```
^[a-z0-9]+(?:[._][a-z0-9]+)*@(?:\w+\.)+\w{2,3}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `(?:[._][a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat matching either `.` or `_` and 1+ one of the listed
- `@` Match literally
- `(?:\w+\.)+` Repeat 1+ times matching 1+ word chars and `.`
- `\w{2,3}` match 2-3 word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ITCNqd/1)

**Note** that this pattern accepts a limited set of email addresses allowing only to match `\w`